# Default Paper Size Setting on Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I have developed asp.net web form with crystal report on visual studio 2008. I set the default paper size to "custom size". But when i publish the web site, it comes crystal report viewer always render to A4 size.

I have too add code to set paper size to my "custom size" in code behind. But when i publish the website again, it shown an Error message "could not load report"

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

`Private Sub frmPrinterOption_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim i As Integer
        xmlDoc.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\Printer.xml")
        Dim xNodeBase As XmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        Dim xNode As XmlNodeList
        xNode = xNodeBase.SelectNodes("//Print//PrintName")
        For i = 0 To xNode.Count - 1
            Me.PrinterTextEdit.Text = (xNode.Item(i).ChildNodes(0).Value)
        Next i
       xNode = xNodeBase.SelectNodes("//Print//PaperSize")
        For i = 0 To xNode.Count - 1
            Me.PrintSizeTextEdit.Text = (xNode.Item(i).ChildNodes(0).Value)
        Next i
End Sub
    Private Sub cmdSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSave.Click
        Dim xNodeBase As XmlNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement
        Dim xNode As XmlNodeList
        xNode = xNodeBase.SelectNodes("//Print//PrintName")
        xNode.Item(SIndex).ChildNodes(0).Value = Me.PrinterTextEdit.Text
        xmlDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\Printer.xml")
        xNode = xNodeBase.SelectNodes("//Print//PaperSize")
        xNode.Item(SIndex).ChildNodes(0).Value = Me.PrintSizeTextEdit.Text
        xmlDoc.Save(Application.StartupPath + "\Printer.xml")
        MsgBox("Saved Successfully.......", MsgBoxStyle.Information + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub`